# Count specific field in array

Tags: php, count

I have an array (paint) where the output looks like this:

```
array(3) {
   ["id"]=> string(1) "2"
   ["type"]=> string(1) "O"
   ["number"]=> string(1) "1"
}

array(3) {
   ["id"]=> string(1) "3"
   ["type"]=> string(1) "W"
   ["number"]=> string(1) "3"
}
array(3) {
   ["id"]=> string(1) "4"
   ["type"]=> string(1) "W"
   ["number"]=> string(1) "5"
}
```

Etc.

What I am trying is how often the type field contains W.
So in this case I should have an output of 2. 
He should skip the first because there the type field is O.

What I tried:

```
 $sum = count($paint["type=W"]);
```

That doesn't work though.
Is it possible to just count how often the type value is W?

Comment: `$sum = count($paint["type=W"]);` maybe a little typo just insert the ]

Comment: @North-Wind: That might not contain the syntax error but will still not do what Robbert wants.

Comment: I edited this in my first post. But that is still not working.

Comment: What is the relation between the subsequent arrays? Is it a 2 dimensional array? Are the arrays retrieved from something?

Comment: use `array_column` and `array_count_values` to get desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a simple for loop?

```
 var count = 0;
 for (var i =0; i< array.length; i++) {
      if($paint[i]['type'] === 'W'){
           count++;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Now this assumes a 2D array? That information is not in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$typeW = array_filter($array1, fucntion($sub) {
    return $sub['type'] === 'W';
});
echo count($typeW);
```

Comment: This solution assumes it is a 2D array, we don't know that.

Comment: Otherwise the question does not make much sense at all :(

Comment: The arrays could be fetched rows from a database. Fetched one by one.

Comment: @Robbert: Ah, so it is a 2D array after all, thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this simple one will be helpful. Here we are using `array_column` on array to get all the values having key as `type` and then counting values using `array_count_values`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/852565)

```
$result=array_count_values(array_column($array,"type"));
print_r($result["W"]);
```

**Output:**
`2`

Answer (score 0):

Using a while loop:

```
<?php
$paint = array();
$i=0;
$x=0;
while($i<count($paint)){
    if($paint[$i][1]=="W"){
        $x++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

echo "result: $x"; --> 2

Comment: This is just ugly, why not use a `foreach` loop?

Comment: That's a matter of taste, my friend.

Comment: @t1gor: Yes, it is, but also experience. A `foreach` loop has a build-in counter, you cannot got wrong with that. With a `while` loop you might get lost in the `$x++;` - `$i++;`, mixing them up and cause a difficult bug. A `while` loop should be used in cases were you don't have a simple counter, even a `for` loop would be better here because it keeps the counter together in one place.